# Cannot add log4j2 to JavaFX project using VS Code and Maven

Tags: maven, javafx, package, log4j

I am having trouble adding the log4j2 jar file to a JavaFX program.

Here is my configuration:

- Visual Studio Code version 1.73.1 (extension pack installed)
- Apache
  Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63)
- Maven home:

  ```
  C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.6
  ```
- Environment info:

  ```
  Java version: 19.0.1, 
  vendor: Oracle Corporation 
  runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19 
  Default locale: en_US 
  platform encoding: UTF-8 
  OS name: "windows 10"
    version: "10.0" 
    arch: "amd64" 
    family: "windows
  ```

When I try to add the apache log4j2 library, I get the following error:

[image: The package org is not accessible]

I have added the dependencies to the pom.xml file, then added the code into the .java file, but it still gives the same error.  The app runs fine without the log4j2 library, so I'm pretty sure that I have all of the right dependencies.

Here is the pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafxdemo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.example.App</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And here is the App.java file:

```
package com.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    private static Scene scene;
    final static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(App.class);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        scene = new Scene(loadFXML("primary"), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    static void setRoot(String fxml) throws IOException {
        scene.setRoot(loadFXML(fxml));
    }

    private static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));
        return fxmlLoader.load();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

To recreate this problem, do the following:

1.) Install VS Code

2.) Install a JDK

3.) Setup the JAVA_HOME and set path to the JDK Path, and the JDK binary directory respectively

4.) Start VS Code

5.) Go to the Command Pallet (Ctrl+Shift+P)

6.) Select Java: Create Java Project...

7.) Select JavaFX create from archetype Provided by Maven for Java

8.) leave groupId as "com.example"

9.) leave artifact Id as "demo"

10.) Save it to a folder on the computer

11.) Verify that everything builds successfully

12.) Go to the navigation pane and bring up the generated src\main\java\com\example\App.java file

13.) Run it and you will see that everything is just fine and it runs showing a primary and secondary window

14.) Add in the jar file by clicking on the "+" next to the "JAVA PROJECTS" Maven Dependencies in the navigation pane

15.) When prompted, type in log4j and press enter

16.) Select "log4j org.apache.logging.log4j

17. Verify that the  following is added to the pom.xml file:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
```

18.) import the log4j packages in the App.java file:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
```

19.) Instantiate the Logger variable by adding in the following line into the class:

```
 final static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(App.class);
```

20. Try to run the App.java program, and you will see the failure

This seems to be a very simple thing to do (add the logging functionality) to a Java app by using the Maven dependencies, but I can't seem to get it to work.  I have tried other .jar files, which work fine.

Do I need to import the log4j.jar file using another method?  I thought that this is what Maven is for?

I know that Maven will configure in other dependencies correctly as you can see that it includes the controlsfx-11.1.2.jar file, and I am able to see controls from this on the screen when I add them.

Stumped...

Comment: That doesn't look like the correct maven dependency for log4j, check the [log4j documentation on "Using Log4j in your Apache Maven build"](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html).

Comment: After you fix your dependencies, if you have a `module-info.java`, you need it to have the line `requires org.apache.logging.log4j`.

Comment: I have had some good results, and some confusing results based on the suggestions from jewelsea.  Here is what I found.  I modified the module-info.java and included the "org.apache.logging.log4j".  As soon as I did this, everything was recognized, and I was able to run.  I then updated the dependency and made it look like the link that jewelsea gave.  However, when I did this and deleted the original entry, the same error came back.  So it seems that adding the line to the module-info.java file was the ticket.  I'm not sure why the dependencies that are given by apache didn't work.

Comment: The dependencies that I added were:
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

Comment: The line in the above pom.xml file:
                           
<type>pom</type>
                         
Will also give the error

Comment: With the module-info requiring log4j, and the dependencies on log4j-api and log4j-core mentioned by Wayne in comments, everything builds and works fine for me.  But I use idea rather than vscode as an IDE, so project setup is different.  It would work in vscode as well with correct setup, but I am not familiar enough with vscode to provide advice on that.

Comment: Thank you jewelsea!  I can at least move on now with a working solution.  I appreciate your time spent in answering my issue.